# Canceling `read_line` with `^C`

Tags: rust, concurrency, future, rust-tokio

I'm writing a shell interpreter as a hobby in order to learn Rust.

Here are a few facts about this code:

- In order to catch when users enter `^C` and cancel their input, I use the `ctrlc` crate, as it seems popular.
- To my knowledge, the `loop_exec()` need to be a future. This is where my shell awaits for user input with `io::stdin().read_line(&mut buf)`. Still to my knowledge, it can't be canceled.
- I hence want to run the `loop_exec()` future, kill it when users hit `^C`, and make another with `loop {}`.
- In order to do that, I need to register the `^C` handler to use the `JoinHandle<()>` of the future (`execution`).
- I obviously can't use it at two places (**I have to use it to register the handler AND to await it**) as per how Rust works (borrow-checker). However, I can't clone `execution: JoinHandle<()>` either or use `as_bytes()`. I'm assuming this is in order to protect devs from shooting themselves in the foot, or do things that are never supposed to happen.

Hence, I'm kind of stuck here. Would you have seen that coming and taken a whole different approach, or do I miss just a bit of information ? Heck I am probably missing a whole lot of knowledge in order to arrive at that point.

How would you do things in this situation or more globally ?

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut kill_execution = false;

    ctrlc::set_handler(move || {
        kill_execution = true;
    })
    .expect("should be able to set Ctrl-C handler");

    loop {
        let execution = tokio::spawn(loop_exec());

        let killer = tokio::spawn(async move {
            while !kill_execution {}
            kill_execution = false;
            execution.abort();
        });

        match execution.await {
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(error) => {
                println!("Error while executing the main thread: {:?}", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit

With the combined answers below, I simplified the code to the following:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            error = tokio::signal::ctrl_c() => {
                println!("Ctrl-C received, exiting: {:?}", error);
                break;
            },
            res = loop_exec() => match res {
                Ok(_) => {
                    println!("Success")
                },
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Error in loop_exec: {:?}", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

async fn loop_exec() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut input = String::new();

    stdin.read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");

    // do stuff

    Ok(())
}
```

The problem is still partially to be identified: `^C` won't trigger `tokio::signal::ctrl_c()` [once the listener has been initialized](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/signal/fn.ctrl_c.html).

Comment: Do shells really catch ^C as sigint? My assumption was that they're opening the tty and reading it like any other input.

Comment: Can't tell. After looking at https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/signal/fn.ctrl_c.html and testing on my own, it looks like I can exit with `^C` for a little bit before, presumably, `an OS signal-handler is installed which replaces the default platform behavior when that signal is received`.

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear: `ctrl_c` definitely does catch sigint (it's a bit [complicated](https://docs.rs/signal-hook-registry/1.4.1/src/signal_hook_registry/lib.rs.html#177) but what a misnomer -.-). What I'm asking you is: Is that the right thing to do? Shouldn't you just read the ^C key codes before they ever become a signal? (Like [this random example](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/blob/3035f0138b4cdf3609b0fffb53f4447d53f2b708/src/uu/more/src/more.rs#L333-L341))

Comment: Okay, so, you just gave me the perfect example, and moreover it's coreutils. Using crossterm didn't cross my mind, pun intended. I would have had to use it at one point anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple possible solutions to this problem (for example, wrapping the `JoinHandle` in `Mutex<Option>`, or using a `select` to abort it) but you seem to misunderstand `JoinHandle::abort()`: it will cancel the task **at the next `.await` point**. So if your function does a computationally-intensive task (such as an interpreter), it won't do anything.

Instead, you need to set an `AtomicBool`, and check it every few operations (for example, at each bytecode operation). You should also use `tokio`'s own signal handling and not the `ctrlc` crate, so this will look like this:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let kill_execution = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));

    tokio::spawn({
        let kill_execution = Arc::clone(&kill_execution);
        async move {
            loop {
                tokio::signal::ctrl_c()
                    .await
                    .expect("failed to listen for Ctrl+C");
                kill_execution.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
            }
        }
    });

    loop {
        let execution = tokio::spawn(loop_exec(Arc::clone(&kill_execution)));

        match execution.await {
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(error) => {
                println!("Error while executing the main thread: {:?}", error);
            }
        }
    }
}

async fn loop_exec(kill_execution: Arc<AtomicBool>) -> Result<(), String> {
    // Take input from stdin.

    kill_execution.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
    
    // And every some operations:
    if kill_execution.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
        return Err("Ctrl+C pressed".to_owned())
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that as described in my question, there is no way for me to check for `kill_execution` every few operations. That is because what loop_exec does, really is just wait for an user input with `io::stdin().read_line(&mut buf)` (**which could take a really long time and can't be canceled to my knowledge**). That's why I'm going out of my way to "terminate" the future, pretty much. Appart from that, really good advices, thank you! Most of them I already implemented as of the time I got your answer.

Comment: @AirOne If it is waiting for input, then Ctrl+C should do nothing, because skipping to the next repl line should do nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

Tokio provides a future which resolves on Ctrl+C, `tokio::signal::ctrl_c()`. This, combined with `tokio::select!`, makes it super straightforward to write what you want:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut ctrlc = tokio::spawn(tokio::signal::ctrl_c());

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            _ = &mut ctrlc => break,
            res = loop_exec() => match res {
                Ok(_) => {},
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Error in loop_exec: {:?}", e);
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the answer, but `read_line(&mut buf)` blocks the listening of `^C`

Comment: Nah, it has to do with the specific documentation of ctrl_c, which I didn't read. Try my edited version. Important lesson: always read rust docs :)

Comment: I know. "RTFD" they say. I tested your snippet, and by replacing `loop_exec()` with a buffer and `stdin.read_line`, you get the same result as me. `^C` is not detected. (ref -> comments on the question)

Comment: are you using the standard lib read_line or the Tokio variant? You should be using Tokio's std replacement functions in Tokio async code, otherwise you get blocked.

Comment: tokio's stdin at docs: `For technical reasons, stdin is implemented by using an ordinary blocking read on a separate thread, and it is impossible to cancel that read. This can make shutdown of the runtime hang until the user presses enter`. You put me on the right track though, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## Final edit

Following the multiple answers below, this is the final snippet I'm going with:

```rust
use std::io::{stdout, Stdout, Write};
use std::time::Duration;

use crossterm::event::KeyEventKind::Release;
use crossterm::event::{self, Event, KeyCode, KeyEvent, KeyEventKind, KeyModifiers};
use crossterm::queue;
use crossterm::style::Print;
use crossterm::terminal::{self, ClearType};

fn setup_term() -> Stdout {
    let stdout = stdout();
    terminal::enable_raw_mode().unwrap();
    stdout
}

fn reset_term(stdout: &mut Stdout) {
    terminal::disable_raw_mode().unwrap();
    queue!(stdout, terminal::Clear(ClearType::CurrentLine)).unwrap();
    print!("\r");
    stdout.flush().unwrap();
}

fn print_prompt(stdout: &mut Stdout, prompt: String, buff: String) {
    reset_term(stdout);
    queue!(
        stdout,
        Print(format!("{} ({}) {}", prompt, buff.len(), buff))
    )
    .unwrap();
    stdout.flush().unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    term();
}

fn term() {
    let mut buff = String::new();
    let mut stdout = setup_term();

    let prompt = format!(
        "{}@{}:{} ",
        // get username,
        // get hotsname,
        // get CWD
    );

    print_prompt(&mut stdout, prompt.clone(), buff.clone());

    loop {
        if event::poll(Duration::from_millis(10)).unwrap() {
            match event::read().unwrap() {
                Event::Key(KeyEvent { kind: Release, .. }) => {
                    continue;
                }
                Event::Key(KeyEvent {
                    code: KeyCode::Enter,
                    ..
                }) => {
                    // send buffer and run command
                }
                Event::Key(KeyEvent {
                    code: KeyCode::Char('c'),
                    modifiers: KeyModifiers::CONTROL,
                    kind: KeyEventKind::Press,
                    ..
                }) => {
                    reset_term(&mut stdout);
                    std::process::exit(0);
                }
                Event::Key(KeyEvent {
                    code: KeyCode::Char(char),
                    ..
                }) => {
                    buff.push(char);
                    print_prompt(&mut stdout, prompt.clone(), buff.clone());
                }
                _ => {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Notable points:

- Using futures was useless in this context
- Using `crossterm` or a similar crate allows me to have free control over how the tui reacts
- ...and using `crossterm`'s key events allow me to listen to backspaces, arrows, **and `^C`**, which is perfect.

So, in the end, canceling `read_lines` is not an option. Rather, I'm implementing my own key reading mechanism.

As mentioned before, [coreutils' more](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/blob/3035f0138b4cdf3609b0fffb53f4447d53f2b708/src/uu/more/src/more.rs) was a perfect example for y use case.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but for future reference you shouldn't mix async and sync I/O. So when using Tokio, you should use [`tokio::io::stdin`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.stdin.html) (which is `async` and cancellable) instead of `std::io::stdin`.